# IP over IPv6 tunnel setup

Tags: networking, systemd

I'm trying to set up a IPv4/6 over IPv6 multipoint tunnel with systemd-networkd. Here is my current config:

```
# public.network
...
[Network]
Tunnel=tunnel
...


# tunnel.netdev:
[NetDev]
Name=tunnel-test
Kind=ip6tnl

[Tunnel]
Mode=any
Local=PUBLIC_IPv6_OF_HOST
Remote=any
TTL=255


# tunnel.network
[Match]
Name=tunnel

[Network]
Address=fd00::1/64

[Neighbor]
Address=fd00::2
LinkLayerAddress=PUBLIC_IPv6_OF_PEER
```

This works and my tunnel interface is set up. But if I try to ping fd00::2, I get the following error in my syslog and no packet is sent via the public interface:

```
ip6_tunnel: tunnel: Local routing loop detected!
```

Multipoint tunnel [seems to be supported by the kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/net/ipv6/ip6_tunnel.c#L1133), but I didn't find much documentation on IPv6 tunnels. (only IPv4, which works fine on my machine)

My kernel version is 5.10.0-21-amd64 on Debian 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the answer. You can't use the neighbour table for IPv6. But routes work:

```
[Route]
Destination=fd00::2/128
Gateway=PUBLIC_IPv6_OF_PEER
GatewayOnLink=true
```